# TypeError message in Pythons PIL (v2.6): integer expected, got float

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, typeerror

first time I'm in the forum. Hope I'm specific enough. 
Using ImageChops inside PIL, I'm trying to multiply two images (both mode="L") but I always get the same error message. I've looked everywhere but couldn't find anything useful. I'd greatly appreciate any helpful ideas! 
The relevant part of the code is attached.

```
    def point(self, f, searchImage, technique): # technique - inpaint or bicubic

    dimx, dimy = searchImage.size

    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader: #f.readlines():
        coord = line
        print coord
        if searchImage.size[0] > float(coord[0])+95.5 and searchImage.size[1]\
           > float(coord[1])+95.5: 
            box = (float(coord[0])-93.5,float(coord[1])-93.5,\
                   float(coord[0])+95.5,float(coord[1])+95.5)     # left upper right
        elif searchImage.size[0] < float(coord[0])+95.5 and searchImage.size[1]\
             > float(coord[1])+95.5:
            box = (float(coord[0])-93.5,float(coord[1])-93.5,\
                   searchImage.size[0]-0.5,float(coord[1])+95.5)  # size of box
            # depends on pixel size. A pixel size of 14 micrometer results in a
            # cross size of 189 pixels
        else:
            box = (float(coord[0])-93.5,float(coord[1])-93.5,\
                   float(coord[0])+95.5,searchImage.size[1]-0.5)

        box = (math.floor(box[0]), math.floor(box[1]), math.floor(box[2]),\
               math.floor(box[3])) 

        searchCrop = searchImage.crop(box)

        c_x = int(float(coord[1])) 
        c_y = int(float(coord[0])) 
        abst_y = c_x - int(math.floor(box[1])) - 1 # x shift

        center = num.asarray(searchImage)[c_x,c_y]
        if center == 0:
            center = center + 0.00001 # to avoid division by zero
        val = [num.asarray(searchImage)[c_x-1,c_y+1], num.asarray(searchImage)\
               [c_x-1,c_y-1], num.asarray(searchImage)[c_x+1,c_y-1], \
               num.asarray(searchImage)[c_x+1,c_y+1]] # ERDAS upper right,
        # upper left, lower left, lower right

        val_dict = {0:1,1:-1,2:-1,3:1}
        flag = val_dict[val.index(min(val))]
        if float(min(val))/center > 2. or min(val) > 100:
            flag = 0

        newima = num.zeros( (searchCrop.size[1], searchCrop.size[0]),\
                            dtype = "float")

        Ayo = num.array(int(searchCrop.size[0])*[255]) 
        Ay = num.array((abst_y + flag)*[255] + 3*[0] + ((int(searchCrop.size[0]\
                                                             )-3-abst_y)-flag)*[255]) 
        Ax = num.array(int(searchCrop.size[0])*[0])  
        Kx = num.array(3*[Ayo] + ((int(searchCrop.size[1])-9)/2+flag)*[Ay] + 3*[Ax] \
                       + ((int(searchCrop.size[1])-9)/2-flag)*[Ay] + 3*[Ayo])   

        Kxlist = list(itertools.chain(*Kx))

        i=0
        for y in range(int(searchCrop.size[1])): 
            for x in range(int(searchCrop.size[0])):        
                newima[y,x] = Kxlist[i+y+x]
            i=i+x

        kernel = Image.fromarray(newima)
        kernel = kernel.convert(mode="L")

        # -----
        modified = ImageChops.multiply(searchCrop,kernel)   # Results in an image 
        # where the pixels along the cross axes will get a value of 0
        # ---
```

The error message is the following:

```
File "D:\GIS_dbase\Data\hma_cci\hexagon\KH9_Python\interpolate_cross.py", line 58, in 
 crossInterpolation filledImage = self.p_model.point(f, searchImage, method) 
File "D:\GIS_dbase\Data\hma_cci\hexagon\KH9_Python\interpolate_cross.py", line 207, in 
 point modified = ImageChops.multiply(searchCrop,kernel)   # Results in an image where 
 the pixels along the cross axes will get a value of 0
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageChops.py", line 119, in multiply
 image1.load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1730, in load
 self.im = self.im.crop(self.__crop)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Comment: Check `searchCrop = searchImage.crop(box)`. It's the only bit of the code that you shared that seems to be calling that function and as far as I can tell the box values might get set before the else.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that PIL's crop method takes a tuple of 4 integer values but you are passing it floats. This should work:

`box = tuple([int(math.floor(x)) for x in box])`